# How to notate the magnitude of a tensor in the direction of a particular vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, index-notation

We have $$S=S_{ij}l_il_j$$ where $l_i$ is a unit vector in the direction in which $S$ is evaluated.

If we want to evaluate $S$ in the direction of the vector $a_i$ we would calculate
$$S=\frac{S_{ij}a_ia_j}{|a_i|^2}=S_{ij}\hat a_i \hat a_j$$

If we want to evaluate $S$ in the direction of a differently oriented vector $b_i$ we would calculate
$$S=\frac{S_{ij}b_ib_j}{|b_i|^2}=S_{ij}\hat b_i \hat b_j$$

**How should one notate these two values of $S$ to distinguish them? E.g., would the notation $S(a_i)$ and $S(b_i)$ be valid? What has been used in literature?**

Comment: $S(a)$? (9 more characters)

Comment: @caverac are you asking me or putting forth a possible/suggested notation? Have you seen this notation in literature before?

Comment: I've seen it in the literature

Comment: @caverac great, thank you! +1